# Executing parameterized .exe files via batch script (Windows command line)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to execute an .exe file via a command line script on Windows (batch file). Actually my script does a lot more before executing the file (generating XML config files and such), however, theses parts work just fine, so I will just concentrate on the non working part of the script here.

I think that the spaces in the command to execute the .exe file might be the source of the error. However, when enclosing the line with `" "` it still won't work.

Echoing the line only works with the line enclosed by `" "` (that's why I am guessing that spaces or maybe some special characters or something cause this problem?). The path it echoes is correct though (checked via copy&paste into the explorer. Application started properly).

Here's the error message: `the filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect`

And the relevant code extract:

```
    rem Start .exe file with parameters
    @echo off
    setlocal

    rem List of keydates
    set "list=20131231 20121231 20111231 20101231"
    set "appPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\"
    set "configPath=C:\Users\username\Desktop\batch test\"
    rem [...] more vars here

    for %%i in (%list%) do (
    (

    rem [...] 
    rem Generation of XML file, works just fine
    rem [...]

    )>BatchConfigTest_%%i.xml
    rem Batch file is located in config path, this is why I define no explicit path here
     )


    rem Problem is located here
    rem How do I execute the exe correctly? This approach doesn't work
    for %%i in (%list%) do (

    %appPath%ApplicationXYZ.exe -xmlcommandconfig:"%configPath%BatchConfigTest_%%i.xml

    rem echo "%appPath%ApplicationXYZ.exe -xmlcommandconfig:"%configPath%BatchConfigTest_%%i.xml""
    rem Echo shows correct paths. Copying the paths from the command line and pasting them into the explorer works.

    )

    pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the problem is this line:

```
%appPath%ApplicationXYZ.exe -xmlcommandconfig:"%configPath%BatchConfigTest_%%i.xml
```

This will expand to `C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\ApplicationXYZ.exe` (no quotes) so `C:\Program` will attempt to be executed (which doesn't exist). Also the config XML file is missing a closing quote.

Try updating the above line to:

```
"%appPath%ApplicationXYZ.exe" -xmlcommandconfig:"%configPath%BatchConfigTest_%%i.xml"
```

By placing quotes around the EXE path, it will expand to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\yyy\ApplicationXYZ.exe"` (with quotes) so it should be picked up correctly. Additionally, I added a closing quote to the XML path at the end.